# why does hashicorp vault json config fail with "Error initializing listener of type listener"?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

When using [hashicorp vault](http://vaultproject.io/) version 1.0.2 and the following JSON configuration file in `config.json`:

```
{
  "listener": [
    {
      "tcp": [
        {
            "address": "0.0.0.0:8300",
            "tls_disable": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "storage": {
    "file": {
      "path": "/tmp/foobar"
    }
  }
}
```

`vault server -config config.json` fails with **Error initializing listener of type listener: unknown listener type: "listener"**.

However, with the same configuration in [config.hcl](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl)

```
listener tcp {
   address     = "0.0.0.0:8300"
   tls_disable = 1
}
storage file {
  path = "/tmp/foobar"
}
```

`vault server -config config.hcl` works as expected:

```
==> Vault server configuration:

                     Cgo: disabled
              Listener 1: tcp (addr: "0.0.0.0:8300", cluster address: "0.0.0.0:8301", max_request_duration: "1m30s", max_request_size: "33554432", tls: "disabled")
               Log Level: (not set)
                   Mlock: supported: true, enabled: true
                 Storage: file
                 Version: Vault v1.0.2
             Version Sha: 37a1dc9c477c1c68c022d2084550f25bf20cac33

==> Vault server started! Log data will stream in below:
...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON seems to be correct, try removing the square brakets:

```
{
  "listener": 
    {
      "tcp":
        {
            "address": "0.0.0.0:8300",
            "tls_disable": 1
        }
    },
  "storage": {
    "file": {
      "path": "/tmp/foobar"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it works indeed. I would be very grateful if you could explain how you figured it out :-)

Comment: I have a very similar configuration that works, but it doesn't have square brakets. And there is no reason to use square brackets near "listener", since there is only one. Hope this helps :)

Comment: For the record when https://www.hcl2json.com/ converts HCL code like the sample provided by the OP into JSON it also includes the unnecessary square brackets.